# My Toshiba Satellite c850 laptop will only display logo screen

Tags: bios, crash, toshiba-laptop

will only show logo, can't get into BIOS to reset defaults, think it has crashed simply from my own stupid plunking, no beeping/noises etc, any suggestions,? tried all the F2, 0, Fn, stuff, no deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should install windows using a disc, or USB. If you have a disc, download Windows by putting the CD in your ROM and then you should see BOOT OPTIONS when you start up your PC, if this doesn't work, try hitting F8 when you boot up the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with LM126, but I think that it will be better to try it using linux. Burn a disk from another computer, and try and see if it boots.

It's kind of hard to say more without more info, but I think you've managed to remove or screw up your OS somehow. If you can get Linux to boot, you can replace Windows (I'm assuming that's what was already on the laptop), or possibly try to repair Windows.

That said, it might also be a BIOS problem, in which case you're kind of in a hole. Maybe someone smarter than me will be able to help you out if that's the case =).

Comment: windows 8 came preinstalled, without a disc, power up, logo appears immediately,tried to boot with a recovery programme on a USB, also, a windows 7 disc, no response, in other words I'm pretty sure the problem is in the BIOS set to load from HDD, computer was given to me in this state, overloaded, never defragged/disc clean up, etc, when I attempted to reset to to factory conditions, yes, I fell down the hole,not one to give up, think the components are all good, run's quietly, access the BIOS/start menu, is the question, if I can get into that, problem will be resolved. Super User is GREAT.

Comment: @CatherineRowe You've marked LM126's answer as accepted -- does that mean you've solved the problem?

Comment: @CatherineRowe unless you set manually set the BIOS to boot from HDD, it should look for a disk in the drive first. Have you tried it with a Linux disk? Also, can we have more information -- do you have an exact model number? You should be able to find 2 -- one on the screen bezel and one on the bottom of the computer.

Comment: Model, c850, PSCBWA-09L001, NO problem not solved, just appreciate your time/effort to help, LINUX DISC? I'm thinking the hard drive is wiped clean as it does not respond to disc inserted/ flash drive,?

Comment: I think you've messed up your bios -- I have nothing. The BIOS isn't stored on the hard drive -- it's stored on a chip on the motherboard, which is really hard to replace in a laptop. Your best bet is probably buying a new laptop. Alternatively, for a cheaper option, you could pull the hard drive, use another computer to install Windows or Linux, buy an [Acer C7 Chromebook](http://goo.gl/fJ6CNZ), and put in the hard drive to make a functional Linux system. You might have to follow instructions to put the laptop in developer mode, or something like that, but that's an SU questionforanothertime.

Comment: Sorry for jammed together letters on the last one; I ran out of characters

Comment: @CatherineRowe Also you shouldn't tick answers as accepted unless they actually fix the problem.

Comment: oh, ok didn't know that, evamvid.